# Distance between a point and a curve

Tags: distance

I have the general equation of an elipse and a point P0:

```
elipse=0.31368-0.113863x-0.00127066x^2+0.00329003y+0.000817666xy+0.0000929297y^2
P0={-6.4,172.0}
```

I would like to find the point on the curve which has the shortest distance from P0. What would it be the best solution? Is there a way to use Near function not only with tables?

Comment: Does this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959698/distance-from-given-point-to-given-ellipse - give you what you need to answer your own question ?

Comment: 0.31368-0.113863x-0.00127066x^2+0.00329003y+0.000817666x*y+0.0000929297y^2==0 determines a hyperbola, not an ellipse.

Comment: This is the result from a FindFit applied to some points, i haven't check the fit yet...I wanted to write the full code before

Answer (score 7):

We can use [`RegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance.html):

```
ellipse = 0.31368 - 0.113863 x - 0.00127066 x^2 + 0.00329003 y + 0.000817666 x y + 0.0000929297 y^2;

P0 = {-6.4, 172.0};

RegionDistance[ImplicitRegion[ellipse == 0, {x, y}], P0]
```

> ```
> 37.5323
> ```

The nearest point can be found in a similar fashion:

```
RegionNearest[ImplicitRegion[ellipse == 0, {x, y}], P0]
```

> ```
> {-43.9319, 172.17}
> ```

Comment: And is this the x or the y of the point on the ellipse?

Comment: That's the distance. you can use `RegionNearest` to find the point.

Comment: could I use RegionNearest when a region is defined by solutions of a given differential problem?

Comment: In principle it can work with anything that is [`RegionQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionQ.html). If you have a curve defined by an equation, wrapping it in `ImplicitRegion` gives a valid input.

Answer (score 4):

The given conic is not an ellipse. It is a hyperbole.

```
elipse = 0.31368 - 0.113863 x - 0.00127066 x^2 + 0.00329003 y + 0.000817666 x y + 0.0000929297 y^2
P0 = {-6.4, 172.0};
sol = NMinimize[{(P0 - {x, y}).(P0 - {x, y}), elipse == 0}, {x, y}];
dist = Sqrt[sol[[1]]]


gr1 = ContourPlot[elipse == 0, {x, -100, 50}, {y, 100, 250}, PlotPoints -> 25];
gr2 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[P0]}];
grn = Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x, y} /. sol[[2]]]}];
Show[gr1, gr2, grn]
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could `Minimize` or `NMinimize` either `Norm[P0 - {x, y}]` or `EuclideanDistance[P0, {x, y}]`